# How can 'Prefix new alias names with the node name of the cell' in WebSphere 7 be set using Jython?

Tags: jython, websphere-7

In WebSphere 7 (fix pack 25) I would like to set the following value:

'Prefix new alias names with the node name of the cell'

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be logged using admin scripting when using the WebSphere 'Integrated Solutions Console'.

Can someone please let me know how can this setting be set using jython. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to set the property directly, but you can get the behaviour you are looking for another way. Instead of using AdminTask.createAuthDataEntry, you can use AdminConfig.create.

`security = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:'+AdminControl.getCell()+'/Security:/')
AdminConfig.create('JAASAuthData',security, [["alias", "aliasWithoutPrefix"],["userId", "myUser"],["password", "myPassword"]])`

This will create a J2C auth entry with the alias 'aliasWithoutPrefix'.

Hope this helps!